# Putting two or three images in two column article in one row

Tags: latex

I'm using aps article based LaTeX template and I would like to put two pictures next to each other (with captions) in a two column article, so that they would span across the both columns.

I've used minipage inside figure option (works in one column article) but I cannot get the desired result. I'd like it to look like this:
[how I wish that it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS43r.png)

So the example has only one caption, but that's irrelevant. I'd like to put two pictures next to each other so that they would be on top of the page.

Any suggestions? Thanks : )

Comment: This question should be moved to TeX forum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Voting to close the question 6 years after it was made... Great job guys! xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using `RevTeX`. As @thouis said, you use the `\figure*` environment to span a figure across the entire page. To put more than one figure, use the `subfigure` package. It looks something like

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \mbox{
    \subfigure[<subfigure caption here>\label{subfigure label}]{\includegraphics[scale/width]{<filename>}}\quad
    \subfigure[<subfigure caption here>\label{subfigure label}]{\includegraphics[scale/width]{<filename>}}\quad
    \subfigure[<subfigure caption here>\label{subfigure label}]{\includegraphics[scale/width]{<filename>}}
  }
  \caption{<main figure caption here>}
  \label{main figure label}
\end{figure}
```

You can adapt this for the `\figure*` environment.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I had to remove extra captions and \mbox but it works. The problem was in image size.

Answer (score 0):

\figure*{} doesn't work?  This is the usual way to create multi-column spanning figures.